# Imap folder shared mailbox - BAD Command received in Invalid state

Tags: java, email, imap

Using JavaMail i have problems updating an imap folder of a shared mailbox or just listing all folders of the shared mailbox.
*(Updating folder of main account is no problem)*

Mail provider is: office365

```
final Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", true);
props.put("mail.imap.auth", true);
props.put("mail.imap.ssl.trust", "*");
props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", true);
props.put("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", true);
props.put("mail.imap.auth.ntlm.disable", true);
props.put("mail.imap.auth.gssapi.disable", true);

final Session mailSession = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(props);
mailSession.setDebug(true);

final Store store = mailSession.getStore("imap");

store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, "user@domainname.de/Info", "******");
// A1 LOGIN user@domainname.de/Info ******
// A1 OK LOGIN completed.
// A2 CAPABILITY
// * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
// A2 OK CAPABILITY completed.
// DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
```

**A: Get List of folders**

```
final Folder[] f = store.getDefaultFolder().list(); // list() throws exception
// A3 LIST "" "%"
// BAD Command received in Invalid state.
```

**B: Update particular folder**

```
final Folder folderSentItems = store.getFolder("Sent Items");
folderSentItems.open(Folder.READ_WRITE); // throws exception
// BAD Command received in Invalid state.
message.setFlag(Flag.SEEN, true);
folderSentItems.appendMessages(new Message[]
{
    message
});
store.close();
```

Wether I retrieve all folders a) or update any folder B, I get this exception:

```
Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: BAD Command received in Invalid state.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What's the name of the shared folder? % often doesn't match such things (% does not match the hierarchy delimiter). But I don't see why it's BAD, though. It ought to list at least the inbox.

Comment: I updated my answer for both cases. `%` is from imap and javamail protocol and accessing with mailbox that is not shared it works.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually being shared that matters? Could it be the presence of e.g. / or space in the folder name?

Comment: Jep, definetly. Updating same folder of the main user mailbox is no problem.

Comment: I have the "same" problem, though with .NET and using S22.Imap, connecting to outlook.office365.com on port 993 :(

Comment: I contacted microsoft and they first also had a look at my code remotely just to tell me later that they do not support 3rd party implementations. So i am still stuck with this.

Comment: I found this: http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/158/t/163878.aspx. It looks like things changed back then, and what you are trying did work for one chap (at the bottom), but it doesn't work for you or I. :(

Comment: This is really a shame of microsoft. A workaround maybe is to send via `bcc` to the same shared mailbox and redirect it to the sent folder. At least in my case this would be sufficient right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of searching and testing various user name combinations the following worked for me:

The trick was **not** taking the `alias` shown in the *outlook.office365.com* admin panel but rather taking the user-name (may be the `UserPrincipalName UPN`) from admin panel *portal.office.com*.
Also using a forward slash.

The final login name in format: `user/shared-mailbox-user-name`

**Example:**

**domain:** example.com
**user:** user@example.com
**password:** abcdefg
**shared-mailbox:** info@example.com
**shared-mailbox-user-name / UPN:** G1234567890123456789@example.com

```
props.put("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", true);
props.put("mail.imap.auth.ntlm.disable", true);
props.put("mail.imap.auth.gssapi.disable", true);

store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, "user@example.com/G1234567890123456789@example.com", "abcdefg");
```

**Update**

Office365 admin allows us now to update the `user-name UPN` so that we can use the shared mailbox itself. Then it would look like this

```
store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, "user@example.com/info@example.com", "abcdefg");
```

Answer (score 1):

I started getting this message last night from my imap connection to office365.

After reading [this](http://www.cknotes.com/?p=328) I was able to fix it by adding this to my connection properties:

```
props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl", "true")
```

(This is in scala, of course in java you'll need a semicolon...)

The timing of this is interesting.  Everything was working fine without it up until today.  Microsoft must have done something with their SSL implementation.  Any chance they're using openssl? :-)